# Sorting columns from two files with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two input files

```
28a39a289906c01159f999a68996091a tom@dong.com
274d1d2c7e931fb55ac0c91dd41f2be7 go@far.com
44d25d3b1b70b240d5058f1be1cef576 person@domain.com
2227a768f6d253b7bf81bb4ecb15b52d person@gmail.com
```

and

```
28a39a289906c01159f999a68996091a
274d1d2c7e931fb55ac0c91dd41f2be7
44d25d3b1b70b240d5058f1be1cef576
2227a768f6d253b7bf81bb4ecb15b52d
```

i'm trying to exclude all the rows in file 1 where file2 and file1 have a matching column 1.

md5 suppression.

What i could find was `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$2]}' $1 $2`

which i know is pretty close just not sure what i did before to do what i want to do now.

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR{md5[$1];next}(!($2 in md5)){print $1}' $1 $2

Comment: Any reason you need to do this in awk? It could be done easier other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order doesn't matter (i.e. just exclude all emails with an md5 in the exclude file) and you're not wedded to awk, use [`join`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?join):

```
join -v 1 -j 1 <(sort emails) <(sort excludes)
```

`-v 1` tells it to print lines in the first file (emails) that don't have a corresponding line in the second file (excludes).
`-j 1`  tells it to only look at the first column of each.

---

If you want to use awk, I believe this should work:

```
awk 'NF==1{exclude[$1]++} NF==2&&!exclude[$1]' excludes emails
```

Or if the two files correspond line-by-line and you only want to exclude, e.g. line 2 if both have the same hash on that particular line, use this:

```
awk 'NF==1{hash[FNR]=$1} NF==2&&hash[FNR]!=$1' excludes emails
```

Comment: I can finally see what the last example is trying to do, if your `FNL` is meant to be `FNR`. I presume "lobbed up" means "not-in-order". Here, in Australia, "to lob up" means "to turn up unexpectedly (a person)", so figuring out how that and `FNL` were related was "interesting"... (+1) for a good answer...

Comment: @Peter.O Yes, `FNR`; "lobbed up" was an input error on the tablet I was using. I've reworded it and tested now.

Answer (score 2):

This has the benefit that the files can go in either order:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -u --check-chars 32 | grep -E '.{33}'
```

`sort file1 file2` is combining and sorting the files in preparation for uniq.

`uniq -u --check-chars 32` considers only the first 32 characters, and with `-u`, prints only the unique lines.

`grep -E '.{33}'` prints only the lines containing 33 or more characters.

**EDIT**

As Peter.O points out, this *does not handle* the case where two or more entries in the files list have the same md5. In that case, those files will not be printed. I like the `join` solution the best.

However, this logic *depends on all separate files having unique md5's*, which is a bad assumption depending on the use of this output. Here is an example of a backup script using the md5sum logic. Though the `join` logic correctly identifies both fileA and fileB (unlike my solution), there is still a problem:

```
echo "hello world" > fileA
cp fileA fileB
./backup_script.sh
cp fileA fileC
./backup_script.sh
```

Did the op indend fileC to be backed up?

Comment: It is an interesting approach, but it does not print unmatched lines for which  there is more than one with the same unmatched key

Answer (score 1):

This command should work:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$0;
    next
  }
  { if ( a[$1] ) delete a[$1] } 
  END { 
    for ( md5 in a ) { 
      if ( a[md5] ) { print a[md5] } 
    } 
  }
' file1 file2
```

Comment: This prints only the last unmatched line when there is more than one line with the same unmatched key.